# Windows Server 2003: start program on event in event viewer

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, windows-event-log, eventviewer

With windows server 2008 you can start a program using scheduled task triggered by event on event viewer.

Is there a way to emulate this with Windows Server 2003?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using event triggers (EVENTTRIGGERS.EXE on Win2k3), see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell to monitor the eventlog for certain events. Here's a script someone wrote for this very purpose.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ed188912-1a20-4be9-ae4f-8ac46cf2aae4

Answer (score 1):

You can use vbscript (WMI) to create an Event Notification Query and respond to specified events according to your needs...
Something like this:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    {impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\.\")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _     
("Select * from __instancecreationevent where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_NTLogEvent'") 
Do 
  Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent 
  strTimeWritten = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.TimeWritten
  strSource  = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.SourceName
  strType  = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.Type
' etc
loop
```